# How to implement DbDongle::convertTimestamps as workaround of invalid timestamps with MySql strict

Tags: octobercms

Coming from here: https://octobercms.com/support/article/rn-4

This question comes to mind: do all tables originally made with ...

`$table->timestamps();`

... needs to be updated with the solution stated in the article?

And also, do I have to re-write the old migration scripts to make all custom timestamp columns nullable? Like:

`$table->timestamp('col_name')->nullable();`

Note: using the new method from the article

`DbDongle::convertTimestamps('users', ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'last_login']);`

... renders the plugin useless for older October instances. This is a huge drawback imho. How do other authors deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay on an older version of October:

1. Ignore these instructions
2. Add `'strict' => false` to your database config

If you are using the latest version of October (Laravel LTS):

1. Fresh installs using `->timestamps()` are created to be nullable from the start
2. No action is required

If you are upgrading from an old version of October to the latest:

1. Use the `convertTimestamps` method to patch the database

Comment: If I want to stay on older version of OC (OctoberCMS) I cannot update the plugin, because it uses a function not present at older version of OC.

Comment: In the end I think if you want the newest version of the plugin, you also need to update OC. Right?

Comment: Correct, all the boats rise with the water in October. Update plugin and core together.